# Are these homebrew feats balanced with the official feats?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, homebrew, balance

Are the following homebrew feats balanced with the official feats?

> ## Dart Master
>
> - You gain proficiency in darts, if you do not already have proficiency.
> - You have a +1 bonus on any attack rolls to throw a dart.
> - You can use your darts as melee weapons.
> - Your darts crit on 19-20.
> - Your darts ignore half cover, get a -2 penalty for 3-quarters cover, and a -5 penalty for full cover.
>
> ## Reflexive
>
> Twice per short rest, you gain an extra bonus action or an extra reaction on your turn.
>
> ## Maximized Spell
>
> When you cast any spell, you can choose to do the maximum damage possible, setting all damage dice to their maximum values. However, at the end of your turn you must make a DC 20 Constitution saving throw or suffer one level of exhaustion. You must choose to maximize before you know whether the spell hits.
>
> ## Precise Spellcasting
>
> Once per day, you can gain a +10 bonus to a spell attack roll.  You must decide to gain this bonus before you roll.
>
> ## Helpful
>
> You can make the Help action as a bonus action.

Comment: This is five questions, not one. You’re totally welcome to ask five questions, but please do it as five separate Questions. Our system works best that way, and as a bonus, it will get you better answers quicker.

Comment: @rpgstar Please do not put answers (even partial ones) in the comments. Such comments will be removed. Comments are only for attempting to improve  or clarify the question. See [here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6533/should-users-refrain-from-answers-or-partial-answers-in-comments/6534#6534) for our policy.  Thanks!

Comment: Just to be totally transparent: I voted to close for the reason KRyan states above. I'd be happy to see any of these individually posted as questions, but the bulk question seems too broad to me.

Comment: Wouldn't it be spammy to post 5 similar questions?

Comment: @qazwsx As long as they are different questions, no. And asking about different custom feats results in 5 completely different questions so you are fine there. And you will likely get *much* better answers that way.

Comment: How does one throw a dart through full cover (like a solid wall) and still hit?

Comment: @Ruse The idea is that it curves around the corner.  The issue is, regardless of the benefit of not having LoS from Full Cover that normally blocks ranged attacks, you're still attacking an Unseen target, so you'd have disadvantage and -5 to your hit.  Disadvantage is about a -4 average in the first place, so you'd be looking at a -9 to hit.  I'd just remove the crit range and have it say it "ignores all cover", so you'd still get the disadvantage from attacking an unseen target, but can still attempt the attack.

Comment: @DanielZastoupil even if that is the intent, the feat allows far more than that. The enemy could be in a sealed room or burrowing 40 feet underground and I somehow would still have a chance to hit.

Comment: @Ruse I could really see that being an amusing spell.  "Unrelenting Missile". Choose a creature in your mind, DM chooses a difficulty of hitting the creature.  Based on the difficulty, it hits the creature somewhere between next round and next week.  Divination spell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### These are somewhat more overpowered than standard feats

Naturally, in your game, you can hand out whatever feats you wish, but I feel that these are somewhat more powerful, or not in keeping with the design philosophies of 5th edition:

Dart Master: +1 to attack with a certain weapon generally doesn't happen in 5th edition feats. Note that Crossbow Expert and Great Weapon Master don't have this benefit.

Reflexive: The optimal use of this is something like an extra attack or two each combat. Not exceptionally unbalanced, although it would give someone two bonus actions in one turn, which may be uncommonly useful.

Maximized Spell: Dealing maximum damage is exceptionally powerful. This is one of those abilities which is overpowered and balanced by a large penalty, which usually involves the players finding a way to ignore the penalty. In this case, the penalty can be ignored simply by long-resting between combats, which isn't something I'd want to encourage. The saving throw means you will often get maximized effect for no drawback.

Precise Spellcasting: Again, the drawback to this is that it only works once per long rest, which can be circumvented by having more long rests. It also has the attack bonus issue, where 5th edition would rather give Advantage.

Helpful: Giving a new bonus action may encourage characters who rarely use their bonus actions to start using them more readily. Two characters with this feat could easily grant each other permanent Advantage. That combination makes this too powerful.

Comment: It might be worth keeping in mind that the Helpful feat copies one specific part of the Mastermind rogue's Master of Tactics feature: "**Starting at 3rd level, you can use the Help action as a bonus action.** Additionally, when you use the Help action to aid an ally in attacking a creature, the target of that attack can be within 30 feet of you, rather than within 5 feet of you, if the target can see or hear you."

Comment: Well spotted. I feel that this ability is still more powerful as a feat, since this opens it up to every class, and allows reciprocal pairs of Help without two Mastermind rogues in the party.

Comment: On the +1 to hit point. Doesn't the lingsword/rapier specialist feat give +1 to something? I thought it was to hit. (I can't remember the exact name right noe)

Comment: Doesn't 3.5 have maximized spells?  How would you implement them in 5e in a balanced way?

Comment: Try as I might, I couldn't find the feat again. It probably didn't leave arcana material

Comment: It's also worth noting that Maximised Spell is arguably much stronger than the Evocation Wizard's Overchannel, which is a level 14 feature.